# Using zeranoe libavcodec build in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am trying to use libavcoded shared build from zeranoe in visual studio 2008. I have tested my application using libavcodec in debug mode and it is running fine. but when i am trying to build the application through release version then it compiles fine but while running it is showing error as  "The procedure entry point CoCreateInstance could not be located in the dynaminc link library avcodec-54.dll" Can any one please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project properties, at the linker section choose optimization. you will see References at the left side, select "Keep Unreferenced Data (/OPT:NOREF)"

(http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html 4.2.1 Linking to FFmpeg with Microsoft Visual C++)